# 3D Matrix Multiplication in R

Tags: r, matrix, tensor

I have a simple problem. I want to multiply a 3D array by another 3D array in R without using a for-loop.

**To illustrate**:

Suppose I have a 1x3 matrix A:

```
[A1, A2, A3]
```

And I have a 3x3 matrix B:

```
[B1, B2, B3 \\
 B4, B5, B6 \\
 B7, B8, B9]
```

My main operation is `A %*% B` resulting in a 1x3 matrix.

But now I want to repeat the process 10,000 times, each with a different A and B of the same dimensions as above. I can use a for-loop

```
for (i in 1:10000) {
     A[i] %*% B[i]
}
```

Then I can store the 10,000 values.

But is there any way to achieve the same thing without using a for-loop. I am thinking of possibly a 3D array multiplication. But I am not sure how to do this in R.

```
Matrix A: 1 x 3 x 10000

[A1, A2, A3] 

Matrix B: 3 x 3 x 10000

[B1, B2, B3
 B4, B5, B6
 B7, B8, B9]
```

Also, would vectorization help?

Can you guys please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are several ways to accomplish this with array multiplication.**  The price you pay is to reformat the matrices into much larger tensors with many zeros.  Those are sparse, by definition, and so the principal cost is the overhead for conversion.  It's actually superior to a loop by the time you have 10,000 arrays to multiply.

Let `n` by the number of (A,B) pairs and `k`=3 the dimension.

The sleekest solution seems to be to reorganize the `n` rows of `A` (an `n` by `k` matrix) into an `n*k` by `n*k` block-diagonal matrix of `k` by `k` blocks.  Block `i`, `i`=1..`n`, contains row `i` of `A` in its top row and otherwise is zero.  Multiplying this (on the right) by `B` (arranged as a `k*n` by `k` matrix consisting of a "stack" of `n` blocks of dimension `k` by `k`) computes all the individual products, depositing them at rows 1, k+1, 2k+1, ..., of the result, where they can be picked out.

```
f3 <- function(a, b) {
  require(RcppArmadillo) # sparseMatrix package
  n <- dim(b)[3]
  k <- dim(b)[2]
  i0 <- (1:n-1)*k+1
  i <- rep(i0, each=k)
  j <- 1:(k*n)
  aa <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x=c(t(a)), dims=c(n*k, n*k))
  bb <- matrix(aperm(b, c(1,3,2)), nrow=n*k)
  t((aa %*% bb)[i0, ])
}
```

As you can see, the array operations are basic: create sparse matrices, transpose arrays (with `aperm` and `t`), and multiply.  It returns its results in a `k` by `n` array (which you may transpose if you prefer), one result vector per column.

As a test, here is a brute-force loop using the same array data structures.

```
f1 <- function(a, b) sapply(1:nrow(a), function(i) a[i,] %*% b[,,i])
```

We may apply these solutions to the same input and compare the results:

```
#
# Create random matrices for testing.
#
k <- 3
n <- 1e6  # Number of (a,B) pairs
a <- matrix(runif(k*n), ncol=k)
b <- array(runif(k^2*n), dim=c(k,k,n))

system.time(c1 <- f1(a,b)) # 4+ seconds
system.time(c3 <- f3(a,b)) # 2/3 second

mean((c1-c3)^2) # Want around 10^-32 or less
```

The results aren't completely equal, but their mean squared difference is less than 10^-32, showing they can be considered the same up to floating point roundoff error.

The array-oriented procedure `f3` is initially slower than the looping procedure `f1`, but catches up by the time `n` is 10,000.  After that it's about twice as fast or better (on this machine; YMMV).  Both algorithms should scale linearly in `n` (and the timing suggests they do, at least out to `n`=10,000,000).

Comment: `sparseMatrix()` is not defined by the RcppArmadillo package. Did you intend to require the Matrix package instead?

Comment: +1 for the neat sparse matrix solution. The loop approach can be implemented more efficiently though -- see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your `A` and `B` are `list`s, you can use `mapply()`:

```
> nn <- 1e1
> set.seed(1)
> A <- replicate(nn,matrix(rnorm(3),nrow=1),simplify=FALSE)
> B <- replicate(nn,matrix(rnorm(9),nrow=3),simplify=FALSE)
> head(mapply("%*%",A,B,SIMPLIFY=FALSE),3)
[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.193976 0.1275999 -0.6831007

[[2]]
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.371143 1.860379 -1.639078

[[3]]
          [,1]       [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.8250047 -0.6967286 1.949236
```

Answer (score 1):

**The for-loop is more efficient than you think**

Your problem of multiplying `n` (A,B) pairs is not equivalent to tensor multiplication in the usual sense, although whuber has presented a very neat way of turning it into a matrix multiplication by stacking the Bs as blocks in a sparse matrix.

You have said you want to avoid a for-loop, but the for-loop approach is actually very competitive when programmed efficiently, and I would suggest that you reconsider it.

I will use the same notation as whuber, with A of dimension n x k and B of dimension k x k x n, for example:

```
n <- 1e4
k <- 3
A <- array(rnorm(k*n),c(n,k))
B <- array(rnorm(k*k*n),c(k,k,n))
```

A simple and efficient for-loop solution would go like this

```
justAForLoop <- function(A,B) {
  n <- nrow(A)
  for (i in 1:n) A[i,] <- A[i,] %*% B[,,i]
  A
}
```

producing an n x k matrix of results.

I have modified whuber's `f3` function to load the Matrix package, otherwise the `sparseMatrix` function is unavailable. My version of `f3` is very slightly faster than the original because I've eliminated the last matrix transpose before returning the result.
With this modification, it returns identical numerical results to `justAForLoop`.

```
f3 <- function(a, b) {
  require(Matrix)
  n <- dim(b)[3]
  k <- dim(b)[2]
  i0 <- (1:n-1)*k+1
  i <- rep(i0, each=k)
  j <- 1:(k*n)
  aa <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x=c(t(a)), dims=c(n*k, n*k))
  bb <- matrix(aperm(b, c(1,3,2)), nrow=n*k)
  (aa %*% bb)[i0, ]
}
```

Now I rerun whuber's simulation in a fresh R session:

```
> k <- 3
> n <- 1e6
> a <- matrix(runif(k*n), ncol=k)
> b <- array(runif(k^2*n), dim=c(k,k,n))
> 
> system.time(c1 <- f1(a,b))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.40    0.09    3.50 
> system.time(c3 <- f3(a,b))
Loading required package: Matrix
   user  system elapsed 
   1.06    0.24    1.30 
> system.time(c4 <- justAForLoop(a,b))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.27    0.00    1.26
```

The for-loop approach is actually the fastest by a narrow margin. It is very much faster than `f1`, which relies on `sapply`. (My machine is a Windows 10 PC with 32Gb RAM running R 3.6.0).

If I run all three methods a second time, then `f3` becomes the fastest because this time the Matrix package is already in the search path and doesn't have to be reloaded:

```
> system.time(c1 <- f1(a,b))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.23    0.04    3.26 
> system.time(c3 <- f3(a,b))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.33    0.20    0.53 
> system.time(c4 <- justAForLoop(a,b))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.28    0.01    1.30
```

However `f3` uses more RAM than the for-loop. On my PC, I can run `justAForLoop` successfully with `n=1e8` whereas `f1` and `f3` both run out of memory and fail.

**Summary**

A direct for-loop approach is much more efficient than `sapply`.

For your problem with `n`=10,000 matrix multiplications, running the for-loop is simple and efficient, taking <0.02sec. By contrast, merely loading the package with sparse matrix functions requires about 2/3sec.

For `n` between 1-10 million, whuber's sparse matrix solution starts to outperform, especially if the Matrix package is already loaded.

The for-loop uses the least RAM of the three methods. For `n` at 100 million on my PC with 32Gb RAM, only the for-loop approach works.

Comment: Very well done--thank you.  You probably already know that I especially appreciate the analysis of the tradeoff in computational resources. :-)  I would expect the sparse matrices to have around a 100% to 200+% storage overhead, depending on the data types of their indexes.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, much appreciated! Your sparse matrix solutions did outperform the simple for-loop approach when k=3, but when k is > 10, it becomes worse than the simple for-loop. Do you guys know why?

Comment: I recall testing these procedures with k up to around 50.  The sparse matrix approach still remained faster on my machine, but only by a factor of two or so.  The reason is that there's less to be gained by these tricks because most of the work consists of matrix multiplication and, with large k, that's already being done very efficiently no matter which solution you implement.

Comment: @whuber which machine were you using? Your sparse matrix solution became slower at k=15 on my machine. Do you happen to know why that is? I used the exact code you posted here. For k=3 the computation time on my machine is very close to what you commented up there.

Comment: That's a good question--it's the reason I wrote "YMMV" in my answer.  For these benchmarks I used Microsoft R in Windows on a four physical core Xeon machine, 24 GB RAM.  For some linear algebraic operations this setup is about three times faster than the standard R distribution.  I haven't studied how it scales with large data.

Comment: I see, I used a MSI machine with 8 cores and 16 GB RAM. Hmm...I'm not sure why there is a significant difference between our results.